# Why do we need the Fourier transforms of sin and cos?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, fourier, signal-theory, spectrum

As we know we perform Fourier transform in case of continuous and "non-periodic" functions, while sin and cosine both function is "periodic" function then why we perform Fourier transform of sin and cosine?

Can we perform Fourier transform of periodic function?
If yes then why we perform Fourier transform instead of Fourier series?

Comment: Fourier transforms convert a signal from the time domain to the frequency domain and back.  Which is used depends on which is most useful, which in turn depends on what we're doing.

Comment: What is your suggestion for a much better alternative? biorythms?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking why we can do a FFT of a pure sine or cosine (and get a distribution as answer), or are you asking why, since we decompose aperiodic functions in (infinite) sums of periodic function, the Fourier Series tool is no longer a viable approach?

Comment: I wrote FFT above, when I should have written FT.

Comment: I suggest not closing this question. It's a very interesting (and legitimate) question about why we use some analytical (math) tools instead of others. This has practical implications on signal theory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belong on Math SE.

Comment: I also think it should remain open, especially since it has a good answer tailored to EE.

Comment: No you don't have to, look at wavelet decomposition

Answer (score 3):

Yours is a far better question than it may seem on first reading.

The Fourier transform of a sine/cosine is a pair of Dirac's delta \$\delta\$ functions  at \$\pm f_c\$. Dirac's delta function can be thought as **the continuous frequency equivalent of the discrete frequency coefficients of the Fourier series expansion**.

The reason we mix them up in EE is because of analytical convenience. Look at the following example.

Suppose that, as part of a transmitting system, we have an modulator that takes a baseband signal \$x(t)\$ and modulates a carrier \$\cos(\omega_c t)\$ with it, so that the get a modulated signal \$s(t)=x(t)\cos(\omega_c t)\$.

If we then want to calculate the spectrum \$S(f)\$ of the modulated signal \$s(t)\$ we *do* need the Fourier transform of the carrier \$\cos(\omega_c t)\$. In this case:

$$
S(f) = \frac{1}{2} [X(f-f_c)+X(f+f_c)]
$$

where \$X(f)\$ is the Fourier transform (a.k.a. spectrum) of \$x(t)\$.

Thus, the baseband signal spectral components of \$x(t)\$ have been "moved up the frequency spectrum" around the carrier \$f_c\$. This result is the keystone of radio communications.

But how did we obtain the previous result, which looks deceivingly simple? It is obtained from the convolution of \$X(f)\$ with the Fourier transform of the carrier (the Dirac's delta pair we mentioned at the beginning). This straightforward calculation couldn't have been done without using the Fourier transform of the sine/cosine function. That's why we define it: because we need it.

In the end, the point is that in EE we usually use sine/cosine periodic functions along with aperiodic information-bearing signal, and **we need to analyse them together within the same mathematical framework**: the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, this is a large topic, and I can't and don't even try to answer it, but I can give you some hints:

Even back then, when Mr. Fourier published his transform sin and cos were very well understood. This lead to a wide understanding and later adaption of his concept. In a certain sense the choice of sin was also the most easiest because even if you haven't understood the transform entirely you could still get the "spit a complex signal into a bunch of simple signals" idea.

There are other Fourier style transforms out there as well. It's not only sin and cos. Just to name one examples here:

The Walsh Transform does basically the same as the Fourier Transform but is bases on a group of square wave signals. Yea! One and zero. No nastly floathing point stuff involved :-)

Working with binary signals the Walsh transform has some nice properties if you have to implement it in hardware, but the drawback is, that the results you'll get out of it are in general not so easy to make use off. As easy as the implementation in hardware is, the harder is it to use :-)

Besides these two extremes there are tons of other Fourier style transforms. The largest and most important one is probably the Wavelet transform which does not use a fixed basis function. You can roll your own functions as long as you obey some rules.

Answer (score -2):

By the way, harmonics do not exist. What you see, instead, is the result of correlation with the sin/cos basis functions at N*Fbinspacing, with N being integer.

If your only tool is a sin/cos, the math gets coerced into forcing energy into those "harmonics".

This is useful to know, because you can craft your systems to be more immune to overloads or jamming in presence of what you are told are "harmonics".

Comment: I am baffled by this assertion. Harmonics most certainly do exist and are produced in copious quantities by every musical instrument ever devised, and by oscillators right here in my lab.

Comment: When your only tool is hammer and nail, everything gets hammered or nailed. As I suggest, correlation injects the energy into your system. You have the opportunity to craft the system to tolerate that energy, thus large IP2 and IP3 are valuable in RF systems with channels astride "harmonic" frequencies.

Comment: "Frequency" is merely the number used to describe the periodicity of the basis function showing high correlation with original waveform.

Comment: Will a MCU clock at 100MHz jam a radio at 313MHz? How about at 330MHz? or at 309? at 303? at 301? at 300?  What is jamming, in a radio? How does higher IP2 or IP3 or P1 affect that radio robustness against adjacent-channel energy? notice we can define "adjacent-channel" offset frequency as any number we find useful in examining "harmonics".